# XML node format (add new line/tab)?

Tags: xml, formatting

How to format XML node to match the following format?
How to add new line / tab?

```
<Note description = "Dear Sir /Madam, **(insert new line)** **(insert tab)** This is to inform you ..." />
```

Output:

```
Dear Sir /Madam,

     This is to inform your that the below mentioned vehicle[s] have attracted ...
```

Comment: Use your tab and return keys... unless you had something more specific in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
&quot;&#10;Dear Sir /Madam,&#10;&#10;&#9;This is...&quot;
```

`&#10;` is line feed, `&#9;` is tab. `&quot;` will be replaced with `"`.

Note that you must tell your XML parser to preserve whitespace. Otherwise, `&#10;&#10;&#9;` will get converted into a single space.

Comment: note that when you view\edit your data, some editors might replace these entities. [e.g. &#9; will become actual TAB chracter]. so it depends on how\where you save\edit your data. In my company we ended up with our special keywords as {TAB}, {NewLine} etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> < ! [ C D A T A [ < b r / > ] ] >

instead of

> < b r / >

- remove spaces from the above code.

You can use the same way to write any HTML in XML like bold, underline, italic etc.